# To determine where the function $f(z)=x^2+y^2+i2|xy|$ is differentiable and where it is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

To determine where the function

$$f(z) = x^2 + y^2 + 2 i \lvert x y \rvert$$

is differentiable and where it is analytic.

Here $v=2 \lvert x y \rvert$ so

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{v(x + h, y)-v(x, y)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2 \lvert (x + h) y \rvert - 2 \lvert x y \rvert}{h} \\
\end{align}
At (x,y)=(0,0), we  have $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{v(h, 0)-v(0, 0)}{h}=0$.

Similarly we can show that at (x,y)=(0,0),  $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} =0$.

But if $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ then how to find $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: $f$ can be rewritten as

$$|z|^2\pm\frac{1}{2}(z^2-\bar{z}^2)$$

where the $\pm$ is dependent on which quadrant of the complex plane we are on. Then using the simplified form of the Cauchy-Riemann equations we have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0 \implies z \mp \bar{z} = 0$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, unfortunately. It looks to me as though you're arguing that since our limit is (by algebraic manipulation) less than or equal to an undefined quantity, that then our quantity is itself undefined?

Unfortunately, this isn't a valid strategy. Saying that our quantity is less than an undefined limit isn't anything useful. If you could prove directly that it's undefined that would work.

You may want to recall identities regarding the magnitude of sums of complex numbers.

Comment: As a concrete example, consider a punctured neighbourhood of $0$. Then $$|z| \le |z|\left(1 + \left\lvert \sin\left(\frac1z\right)\right\rvert\right)$$ on this region. The latter has no limit as $z \to 0$ but the former does.

Comment: yes, I understood but then how should I proceed?